# Are there any vertex colouring algorithms which colour regular graphs optimally?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

As the question suggests I am looking for a vertex colouring algorithm preferably exact, which can colour regular graphs optimally. Is there any which is known in literature?

Comment: What is "optimally"? Minimum number of colors?

Comment: yep. Should give the minimum colouring.

Comment: Not in general but if this is meant to be practical then a integer program may work well if your graphs are not too large

Answer (score 1):

No hope. The line graph of a cubic graph is 4-regular, and so its chromatic number is three if and only the cubic graph has an edge 3-coloring. Deciding this is NP-complete.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what Wiki says on [Graph Colorings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Computational_complexity)

> Graph coloring is computationally hard. It is **NP-complete** to decide if a given graph admits a $k$-coloring for a given $k$ except for the cases $k = 1$ and $k = 2$. In particular, it is **NP-hard** to compute the chromatic number.[19] The 3-coloring problem remains **NP-complete** even on planar graphs of degree 4.[20] However, k-coloring of a planar graph is in P, for every k>3, since every planar graph has a 4-coloring.

Further MathWorks knows about [Minimum Vertex Coloring](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimumVertexColoring.html)

> Brelaz's heuristic algorithm can be used to find a good, but not necessarily minimum vertex coloring. Finding a minimal coloring can be done using brute-force search (Christofides 1971; Wilf 1984; Skiena 1990, p. 214), though more sophisticated methods can be substantially faster. A minimal vertex coloring can be found for small graphs using backtracking with `MinimumVertexColoring[g]` in the Wolfram Language package Combinatorica and Brelaz's algorithm can be applied using `BrelazColoring[g]`.

On [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66836/minimal-colouring-of-graph-vertices) they had an example for the first mentioned function...